# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable when i try to add a new element to a tuple

Tags: python

I want to find an element in a matrix, and to add the line and column indexes to 2 tuples, but when i try to assign the new element to any tuple, I encounter this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```
from typing import NewType
import numpy as np

def find(element:int, matrix:np.array) ->tuple:
    '''Returnez un tuplu cu indicii elementului cautat'''
    myTuple = tuple()
    for i in range(2):
        for j in range(3):
            if matrix[i][j] == element:
                myTuple += (i,)
                myTuple += (j,)
                return myTuple


def pos_values(matrix: np.array, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int) -> tuple:
    rows = tuple()
    cols = tuple()
    for myElement in range (a, b):
        theTuple = find(myElement, matrix)
        theLine = theTuple[0]
        theColumn = theTuple[1]
        rows += (theLine, )
        cols += (theColumn, )
    return rows,cols    


mat = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
rows, cols = pos_values(mat, 2, 4, 6, 8)
assert np.all(rows == [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])
assert np.all(cols == [2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0])

mat = -np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
rows, cols = pos_values(mat, 2, 4, 6, 8)
assert np.all(rows == [])
assert np.all(cols == [])

---> 20     theLine = theTuple[0]   
 **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**
```

Comment: If `element` is not in `matrix`, what does `find` return?

Comment: it return none, but i iterate thought an interval, and my matrix is arranged from 0 to 12, and my interval is 2 from 4 ,  so is it possible that the element is not in matrix?

Comment: So if `theTuple = None`, what does `theTuple[0]` result in?

Comment: You are also not looking at all the elements of `mat`. The `stop` parameter of `range` is not included in the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't looking at all the elements of `matrix`, so you don't find some of the elements you are searching for. The elements of `range` don't include `stop`.

Having not found your elements, you then index into the `None` that you got from `find`

As an aside, there is a numpy function that collects indexes where some condition is true:

```
from typing import NewType
import numpy as np

def pos_values(matrix: np.array, a: int, b: int, c: int, d: int) -> tuple:
    elements = list(range(a, b))
    elements.extend(range(c, d))
    return np.where(np.vectorize(lambda x: x in elements)(matrix))


mat = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
rows, cols = pos_values(mat, 2, 5, 6, 9)
assert np.all(rows == [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2])
assert np.all(cols == [2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you! After i changed with range(a, b+1) it worked.